# Why don't my variables change after http request?

Tags: angular, http

```
  larnacaCount=0;
  nicosiaCount=0;
  private array :number[] = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private popupService: PopupService) { }

  makeCapitalMarkers(map: L.Map): any {
    
    
     this.http.get(this.capitals).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.larnacaCount=res.larnaca;   //should return 3
        this.nicosiaCount=res.nicosia;   //should return 1
        console.log(res);
          for (const c of res.features) {
            const lon = c.geometry.coordinates[0];
            const lat = c.geometry.coordinates[1];
            const marker = L.marker([lat, lon]);
        
            marker.bindPopup(this.popupService.makeCapitalPopup(c.properties));
            marker.addTo(map);

          }
          
    });
    this.array.push(this.larnacaCount);
    this.array.push(this.nicosiaCount); 
    console.log(this.array)
    return this.array;    // this array is (0,0)
```

My 2 variables that I try to push in the array appear correctly inside the http request but when that finishes they go back to 0 and 0

Comment: Assign the values inside the `subscribe` block. This is an asynchronous operation, after all (ie. after you call `this.http.get.subscribe(...)` the code doesn't wait for its completion and moves to the next line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http is async per se. In your case order of execution will be:

1. Call this.http.get (but callback will be called later since its an async operation)
   `this.http.get(this.capitals)`
2. Execute sync code (the one where you are pushing elements into array and returning `this.array`)
3. Execute callback of `this.http.get`, where you are assigning values

If you need array value as a return value of your `makeCapitalMarkers` method, then the method should be async one and should have return type of Promise or Observable.